# MS Outlook: A method for presenting the sum of the Total Work column by day

Tags: microsoft-outlook, microsoft-outlook-2013, tasks

I've been using Microsoft Outlook's Tasks to sort work by due date and order by date created/started, and I've started providing estimates in the Total Work column.

I'd like to be able group my tasks by day *and* get a sum of the total work for the tasks due that day to account for capacity.

I'm not afraid to get my hands dirty, so I'm open to any level of solution, but wondered if there isn't an existing method someone's discovered or developed they'd be willing to share.

Cheers~

Comment: Have you researched or tried anything yet?

Comment: I've gone through the options in the program, and I've performed searches online, but haven't seen anything related to to what I'm trying to achieve. I've also examined what can be done with the Field Chooser control and grouping, but I think the solution would involve adding functionality to the Grouping control or another control. It seem way out of the Outlook "box".

Answer (score 1):

You could possibly create a custom field that sum the total work based on due date then write that number into that custom field. It'd be the same number for each task that shares the same due date, but you could update it every time you need to calculate your capacity.

You can also use Microsoft Access to link to Outlook tasks and create a report outside of Outlook.

You can also use Crystal Reports that connects to Outlook as a data source and you can run report off of it also.

Or you can use a [Outlook to CSV free tool to export](http://www.codetwo.com/freeware/outlook-export-thanks) then use Excel to create your report.